# $\mathbb R^n=U \cup V$ where $U, V$ connected open subsets then show that $U\cap V$ connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness, mayer-vietoris-sequence

$\mathbb R^n=U \cup V$ where $n\ge 2$ and $U, V$ open and connected is the intersection $U\cap V$ connected?

My attempt is: to try Mayer Vietoris sequence, since $\mathbb R^n$ is contractible its homology group is $H_k(\mathbb R^n)=\begin{cases}\mathbb Z \quad k=0 \\ 0 \quad else\end{cases}$

And we have reduced short exact sequence as

$$0\to H_0(U\cap V)\to H_0(U)\oplus H_0(V)\to  \underbrace{H_0(\mathbb R^n)}_{\mathbb Z}\to 0$$

Since they are all connected but not necessary path connected and we are not given anything about locally compactness about spaces I cannot conclude that $H_0(U\cap V)\cong \mathbb Z$.

Any hint and answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to prove that if $n\geq 2$ and $\mathbb{R}^n=U\cup V$ with $U$, $V$ connected, then **it follows that** $U\cap V$ must also be connected?

Comment: yes exactly .....

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am just stressing that if U and V are path connected the problem is easy but we are only given that they are just connected open subsets whose union is $R^{n\ge 2}$

Comment: Then don't say they aren't path connected, say they are not necessarily path connected.

Comment: corrected, sorry it is my first time here in math exchange

Comment: Are there open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ which are connected but not path connected? I know examples of connected spaces which are not path-connected, but none. of those are open subsets of $\mathbb R^n.$

Comment: Yes I also know top- sin curves etc. Then to aim is to show they are path connected?

Comment: According to wikipedia, every connected locally path-connected space is path-connected. So connected open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are path-connected. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space

Comment: Yes I also checked it now, then we are done.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Theorems):

> A locally path-connected space is path-connected if and only if it is connected.

An open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is locally path-connected, so it is connected if and only if it is path-connected.

---

The proof of this isn't hard. We'll only prove connected implies path-connected.  The other way (path-connected implies connected) is well-known, following from the fact that $[0,1]$ is connected.

Assume $X$ is connected and locally path-connected. let $x\in X$ and let $U$ be the set of points which are path-connected to $x$ and $V$ the set of all points path-disconnected from $x.$  Then $U\cup V=X$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset.$ We will show $U,V$ are open.

If $y\in U$ then pick a neighborhood $W$ of $y$ which is path-connected. Then every element of $W$ is also path-connected to $x,$ so $y\in W\subseteq U.$ So $U$ is open.

If $y\in V,$ then pick a neighborhood $W$ of $y$ path-connected. Then if any point in $W$ is path-connected to $x,$ $y$ would be. So we must have $W\subseteq  V.$ So $V$ is open.

Since $x\in U,$ $U$ is non-empty, so connectedness means $V=\emptyset,$ and $U=X,$ so $X$ is path-connected.

Comment: To relate it to the question. We say that if $X$ is path connected then $H_0(X)\cong \mathbb Z$ . BUT Can we also say that if $H_0(X)\cong \mathbb Z$ then $X$ is path connected?

Comment: @Ph2223 $H_0(X)$ is the direct sum of groups $\mathbb Z$ where there is one $\mathbb Z$ for every path-connected component. I was assuming you knew this, given your mention of path-connectedness.

Comment: so every X has path component decomposition and thats why we can write them as a direct sum right?

Comment: Yes, $H_0(X)$ doesn't depend on closeness, just path-connectedness. $H_0(\mathbb Q)$ is the same as $H_0(\mathbb Z)$ under their usual topologies. There are no non-constant paths in either.  You can work this out using the definition of homology using chain complexes. In the chain $C_0,$ the generators are points $x\in X$ and the image of $C_1$ is generated by $x-y$ where $x$ and $y$ are path-connected.  @Ph2223